# Weird margins on inline-block elements and unable to vertically align element inside them

Tags: html, css

I think I'm going insane over this now, no idea how to resolve it... please help guys.

I have three divs on a page that should all fit onto one line. They have to be square (with rounded corners) so I have to set a width and a height to keep the 1:1 aspect ratio. I have a heading inside them that should be vertically and horizontally centered. The wording of the heading may change and might run over 2 lines so a simple margin-top is not enough in this case.

First problem: there are weird margins at the top despite there not being anything else affecting that (well there must be but I can't see what). If I float the divs they line up but floating isn't the way to go is it... why is inline-block not working?

Second issue (which is likely related, so I'm posting it in one go) is that I'm unable to vertically center the title divs. Any ideas?

Here's a jsfiddle to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/fydC4/

The HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="nav-left">
    <p id="nav-left-title">In this section&hellip;</p>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="light" href="#">page title here</a></li>
            <li><a class="light" href="#">page title here</a></li>
            <li><a class="light" href="#">page title here</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
        <h1>Assignments</h1>
        <p>Click on the titles of the assignments to find out more.</p>
            <div class="box" id="good-designs">
                <h2 class="box"><a href="#">3 good designs</a></h2>
            </div>

            <div class="box" id="temp">
                <h2 class="box"><a href="#">title here</a></h2>
            </div>

            <div class="box" id="temp2">
                <h2 class="box"><a href="#">title here</a></h2>
            </div>
    </div><!--end main-->
</div>
</div><!--end container-->
```

The CSS:

```
#container {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
}
#main {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 73em;
    padding: 1em 2em 2em;
    background-color: white;
}
#nav-left-title {
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
}
.nav-left{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 14em;
    background-color: #87a8b1;
    padding: 1.1em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
.nav-left li {
    padding: 0.5em 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
h2.box {
    padding: 15px 0;
    margin: 50% 15px;
    margin: auto;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
}
div.box {
    padding: 15px;
    height: 180px;
    width: 180px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
    display:inline-block;
    /* float: left; */
}
#good-designs {
    background-color: green;
}
#temp, #temp2 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you may use two properties to align all your elements

```
vertical-align:middle;

display:inline-table on div.box and 
display:table-cell on h2.box; (for the texts inside your divs)
```

Check this code http://jsfiddle.net/fydC4/16/

Comment: Thank you, that indeed helped! Can we say that as a general rule if we want to align things vertically in the middle, we should use a table-related type of 'display:'? Or is there a way to do it with inline-block somehow?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, replace inline-block with float left.

you are also calling margins twice on some element which are not necessary
here you go 
jsfiddle.net/fydC4/14

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in my initial question, I did not want to float them for other styling reasons. Thanks for flagging the margin issue though!